# CONSTANT issues with Facebook not sharing correct data

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, metadata, facebook-social-plugins

I am using Wordpress and I have tried a variety of different plugins to set meta data on pages and posts (Yoast, WP Open Graph, etc.).

However, it always seems that Facebook doesn't grab the correct data from pages until I run the URL through the Facebook Linter, and once I do that, the picture, title, and description are *magically* perfect.

It's annoying, and it seems like something that should be so easily fixable. Does anybody know why this is happening?